# My metabox class

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I'm using the [class My Metabox class](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox)

```
*-- Custom Post Init Begin --*/  

function mypost_types(){
    register_post_type('video', 
    array(
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __( 'video' ),
            singular_name' => __( 'video'),
            'add_new_item' =>__('Add New video'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit video'),
            'view_item' => __('View video')
        ),

        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' =>  array('title','editor','excerpt','thumbnail','custom-fields')
    );
}   
add_action('init', 'mypost_types');
```

__*_*_____second version after @kaiser comment

```
/*-- Custom Post Init Begin --*/
```

`

```
 function mypost_types(){
{ 
$labels = array(
'name' => __( 'video' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'video' ),
'add_new_item' =>__('Add New video'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit video'),
'view_item' => __('View video')
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' =>     array('title','editor','excerpt','thumbnail','custom-fields')
     );

    register_post_type('video', $args);
}   
      add_action('init', 'mypost_types');`
```

I have a problem to add this class in `register_post_type`. Does anybody know how to implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: More details + code please.

Comment: Could you please edit the Q and format the code properly? Thanks.

Comment: i put the code in the first comment i hope it is fine, thanks

Comment: I reformated it. The problems start with missing quotes, assigning `$label` during calling the `register_post_type` function and such. Please fix this, read about `WP_DEBUG`, then come back and show your error messages.

Comment: i put the code in the main comment see => second version

Comment: Basically it's just a fork of [RW Meta Box Library - see KnowledgeBase on TenderApp](http://meta-box.tenderapp.com). And please: If you write a Q, then you've a preview below. Format your code as well & readble as possible.

Comment: yes i ve read the documentation and the metabox is create fine but i have a problem because the data are unsaved, the documentation is good but dont explain how to set up the custom post.

Answer (score 1):

it says right in the instructions that you just include the class

```
//include the main class file
require_once("meta-box-class/my-meta-box-class.php");
```

you'd put that in whatever file you are using for the code blocks you posted... not in the function you've written.

looks like there is a pretty good section called "Usage" at the link you provided.  you should re-read that and revise your question to explain more clearly what your problem is that is not answered by the provided documentation.

Comment: thanks but i read it and do as the "usage doc" show but i think the main problem is in my cutom post declaration.

Comment: doesn't look like there is anything wrong with your custom post type declaration.  and it isn't really related to your usage of the metabox anyway.  you can copy and paste the sample code provided in the documentation.  there's ONE section that you will need to change to get a metabox on your post type.  in the $config array, the sample has an array for the 'pages' value.  you'll need to change that to array('video')